# How do i perform Gravity data push from HttpServlet

Tags: java, spring, http, servlets, graniteds

Last few days i was playing with GranideDS tutorials (using Spring server and AIR client)
https://github.com/graniteds-tutorials/graniteds-tutorial-data

> "This tutorial shows how to build a simple data application that
>   manages a database of user accounts. All connected clients are
>   notified and synchronized with data updates using a GraniteDS long
>   polling channel."

Unfortunately i cannot find any GraniteDS javascript client library or example.
I created an HttpServlet to manage (add Entity for example) persistense context using http (ajax) requests.

my TestServlet.java

```
@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;     

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext());
        AccountService srvObject = (AccountService) wac.getBean("testService");
            //testService mean spring service annotation parameter
        Account emp = new Account();
               emp.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
               emp.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        srvObject.save(emp);
        response.getWriter().println("OK");
    }
}
```

This method adds an entity correctly but connected client's data are NOT syncronized. How can i notify all clients about new changes?

**UPDATE:**
I was trying to change DataEnabled's publish to PublishMode.ON_COMMIT

```
@DataEnabled(topic="dataTopic", publish=DataEnabled.PublishMode.ON_COMMIT, useInterceptor=true)
```

add to application-context.xml

```
<graniteds:tide-data-publishing-advice/>
```

In this case both air application and servlet causing server error:

> SEVERE: Could not register synchronization for ON_COMMIT publish mode,
>   check that the Spring PlatformTransactionManager supports it and that
>   the order of the TransactionInterceptor is lower than the order of
>   TideDataPublishingInterceptor

And `<graniteds:tide-data-publishing-advice order="-1"/>` does not helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the mode ON_SUCCESS with useInterceptor=true
"useInterceptor=true" is necessary because it's what will make GraniteDS aware of your service which is called completely outside its control

Comment: Hello William. If i place `<graniteds:tide-data-publishing-advice/>` at the end of application-context.xml, that server error does not fires. But, unfortunately, data is not updating anyway.
But i noticed that in this tutorial data is not updating between clients even within GraniteDS control. Have a look in my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092781/connected-flex-clients-are-not-synchronized-with-data-updates-in-graniteds-tutor