# Connected Flex clients are not synchronized with data updates in GraniteDS tutorial

Tags: java, spring, apache-flex, air, graniteds

I am following the instruction in GraniteDS graniteds-tutorial-data tutorial
https://github.com/graniteds-tutorials/graniteds-tutorial-data
Updated version 3.0.1.GA

My environment:

> - Windows 7 64 bit
> - Apache Maven 3.1.1 2013-09-17 16:22:22+0100)
>      Maven home: C:\dev\apache\apache-maven-3.1.1
>      Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor:
>     Oracle Corporation
>      Java home: C:\dev\java\jdk1.7.0_45x86\jre
>     Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
>      OS name:
>     "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
> - java version "1.7.0_45"
>     Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
>    Java
>     HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Steps to reproduce:

1. run   `git clone
   http://github.com/graniteds-tutorials/graniteds-tutorial-data.git`
2. change `"localhost"` to real local IP Adress `"192.168.1.77"` in `graniteds-tutorial-data\client-air\src\main\flex\data.mxml`
3. go to   `cd graniteds-tutorial-data`
4. run   `mvn clean install asciidoctor:process-asciidoc -Dserver=spring -Dclient=air`
5. go to   `cd server-spring`
6. run   `mvn tomcat7:run-war`
7. Install and run "data.air" from graniteds-tutorial-data\client-air\target\ on local computer
8. Install and run "data.air" on other computer (windows XP 32 bit) in local network

   Note: All maven builds are success and firewall on both machines are disabled.

Problem: **adding new entities and updating existing ones from one computer does not reflects data on another computer, data appears only when refresh called.**

From the tutorial description: `"All connected clients are notified and synchronized with data updates using a GraniteDS long polling channel."`

Thank you for help.

**Update**

there is some warnings when run `mvn tomcat7:run-war`:

> [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective
>   model for
>   org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data-server-spring:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   [WARNING] 'parent.relativePath' points at
>   org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data instead of
>   org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-server-spring, please verify
>   your project structure @ line 28, column 13 [WARNING]
>   'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-comp
>   iler-plugin is missing. @
>   org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-server-base:3.
>   0.1.GA, C:\Users\devel.m2\repository\org\graniteds\tutorials\tutorial-parent-se
>   rver-base\3.0.1.GA\tutorial-parent-server-base-3.0.1.GA.pom, line 37,
>   column 21 [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-p lugin is missing. @
>   org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-server-base:3.0.1.GA ,
>   C:\Users\devel.m2\repository\org\graniteds\tutorials\tutorial-parent-server-b
>   ase\3.0.1.GA\tutorial-parent-server-base-3.0.1.GA.pom, line 84, column
>   21 [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war- plugin is missing. @
>   org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-parent-server-base:3.0.1.G A,
>   C:\Users\devel.m2\repository\org\graniteds\tutorials\tutorial-parent-server-
>   base\3.0.1.GA\tutorial-parent-server-base-3.0.1.GA.pom, line 46,
>   column 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with GraniteDS version 3.0.2.GA
https://jira.granitedataservices.com/browse/GDS-1234